# React Js Router showing 404 error on hosting

Tags: reactjs, router

I developed a React Js site and used Router to route through pages.

```
 <Router>
      {/* <NavBar/> */}
      <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
      <Route path="/shop" element={<Shop />} />
      <Route path="/product" element={<Product />} />
      <Route path="/login" element={<LoginScreen />} />
      <Route path="/signup" element={<SingupScreen />} />
      <Route path="/account" element={<AccountView />} />
      <Route path="/forgotPassword" element={<ForgotPassword />} />
      <Route path='*' element={PageNotFound}/>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
```

This is the router and this works when we call it using 'NavLink'. When I type http://example.org/shop in the url its showing 404 error on server. But in localhost it works fine. The router problems occurs when its hosted. Please help me out.

Comment: how are you hosting it? For some platforms, you'll have to some config to reroute to / in case of 404 if it's a single page application. Because the routing is handled by react router

Comment: The hosting is in cpanel

Answer (score 2):

This helped me, Create a .htaccess file in the root folder of the application and add the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: this fixed my problem, thank you.